# A Schwartz kernel type theorem for Sobolev spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, schwartz-distributions

The well-known [Schwartz kernel theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_kernel_theorem) states that a continuous operator from smooth test functions to distributions, $T \colon C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}^n) \to C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}^n)'$ is continuous iff it is of the form $T[f](x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} T(x,y) f(y) \, dy$, where the kernel is a distribution $K(x,y) \in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n)'$.

**Q:** Is there any analog of such a theorem where smooth test functions and distributions are replaced by Sobolev spaces $H^{s}$ or $W^s_p$?

For instance, $H^{s}$ with $s\ge 0$ could play the role of test functions, while those with $s\le 0$ could play the role of distributions. The simplest example of a multiplication operator $T\colon H^0 \to H^0$, where $T[f](x) = t(x)f(x)$ with compactly supported and sufficiently regular $t(x)$, and of course $H^0 = L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$, shows that a simple transcription of the result is false, since $T(x,y) = t(x)\delta(x-y)$, and $t(x)\delta(x-y) \not\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n)$. But $t(x)\delta(x-y) \in H^{-1}(\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n)$. So perhaps for any continuous operator $T\colon H^{s_1} \to H^{s_2}$ there necessarily exists an $s$ made out of $s_1$, $s_2$ and some appropriate shift, such that $T(x,y) \in H^{s}$.

Comment: I think the obstacle is that $H^{\infty}(\mathbb R^n)\to L^2(\mathbb R^n)$ is not nuclear...

Comment: @paulgarrett, could you elaborate? What is that an obstacle to?

Comment: Or, more bluntly, $V=H^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$ is not nuclear, in the sense that there is no _categorical_ tensor product (e.g.) of it with itself. If there _were_ a TVS $V\otimes V$, then we have a Cartan-Eilenberg-type adjunction ${\mathrm Hom}(V\otimes V,\mathbb C)\approx {\mathrm Hom}(V,{\mathrm Hom}(V,\mathbb C))$. That is $(V\otimes V)^*\approx {\mathrm Hom}(V,V^*)$.

Comment: This is a great comment. I was thinking about nuclear spaces but I did not know the subject very well.

Comment: Only barely relevant as I am not even attempting to look at the Schwartz angle, but Thm. 4.4.7 in Duistermaat's book on Fourier Integral Operators (or Thm. 5.4.1 in Duistermaat and Hörmander's FIO II paper) gives some information on the Sobolev regularity of the kernel of a FIO. And of course some FIOs map $H^{s_1}$ to $H^{s_2}$ for some $s_1, s_2$, see e.g. Cor. 4.4.5 in Duistermaat's book.

Comment: @paulgarrett, I've been mulling over this remark about nuclearity, which was again brought up in the answer by thaya. I must say that I'm still having trouble with it. I understand that in general $(V\otimes W)^* \not\approx \mathrm{Hom}(V,W^*)$, with given Sobolev spaces $V$ and $W$. But the spirit of my question is whether it can still be that $\mathrm{Hom}(V,W^*) \approx (V'\otimes W')^*$ for *some* choice of $V'$ and $W'$, possibly some other Sobolev spaces. I don't see how nuclearity rules that out, unless there's some unstated argument at work here that's obvious to others but not me.

Comment: @IgorKhavkine, ah, yes, in that abstraction it's less clear... Let me think about this later...

Comment: ... and just for the record, I think these FIO remarks imply that you cannot possibly hope to do better than $s < s_2 - s_1 - n/2$ (as I guess one can always find a FIO of order $s_1 - s_2$, whose Lagrangian submanifold is locally the graph of a canonical transformation and which has a characteristic point somewhere).

Comment: @UmbertoLupo, thanks for the pointers!

Answer (score 1):

This might be off topic since it has already been pointed out that in the absence of nuclearity you cannot expect such a result in your context. However, the following general remarks might be of interest to you.  If $A$ is an unbounded self-adjoint operator on a separable Hilbert space $H$, which we assume to be $\geq \text{Id}$, then we can define a so-called hilbert scale $H^t$ of spaces, where for positive $t$, $H^t$ is the  domain of definition of $A^t$ and $H^{-t}$ is its dual under the scalar product on $H$.  These can be regarded as abstract Sobolev spaces and if we choose the classical operators (Sturm-Liouville operators, Laplace operators, Schrödinger operators) of mathematical physics, we get a vast spectrum of generalised Sobolev spaces, including the one in the above posting. Using the spectral theorem, we can represent them as so-called weighted $L^2$-spaces.  Thus in general there is no kernel theorem since there is no realisation of bilinear forms on such spaces using measurable kernels.  However, if the operator has a discrete spectrum consisting of a sequence of eigenvalues, say $(\lambda_n)$, then the $L^2$'s are in fact $\ell^2$'s and things work fine. In particular, if the eigenvalues satisfy a condition of type $\sum \dfrac 1 {\lambda_n^\alpha}<\infty$ for some positive $\alpha$, we have nuclearity and so results of the type you are looking for.  It is also possible to get explicit results on the relationship between the indices as requested.